# XSLT accumulate

Tags: xml, xslt, accumulate

I have a parent variable and two child variables for accumulate

I would like to use those two child variables to select two different values

I can only hardcode it to make it works like all other tutorial
for example: $parent[1]/Price and $parent[1]/Quantity

but insteads I want the following:

```
$parent[1]/$child1 where $parent[1] = orders[1]/order and $child1 = price
$parent[1]/$child2 where $parent[1] = orders[1]/order and $child2 = quantity

    <xsl:call-template name="total">
    <xsl:with-param name="pList" select="$parent"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="price" select="Price"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="quantity" select="Quantity"/>   
    </xsl:call-template>

<xsl:template name="total">
    <xsl:param name="pListItem"/>
    <xsl:param name="pAccum" select="0"/>
    <xsl:param name="price"/>
    <xsl:param name="quantity"/>

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$pListItem">
        <xsl:call-template name="total">
          <xsl:with-param name="pListItem" select="$pListItem[position() > 1]"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="pAccum"
           select="$pAccum + $vHead/$price * $vHead/$quantity"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pAccum"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Although it is not clear what your question is (no question is specified at all), I have tried to guess as much as possible and have provided in my answer a complete, short, generic and easy solution to what I believe is your problem. +1 for a difficult beginning. Everything is difficult initially :)

Answer (score 2):

It is not exactly clear what the question is, but my guess is this.

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pPriceName" select="'price2'"/>
 <xsl:param name="pQuantityName" select="'quantity1'"/>


 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:call-template name="totalSales">
   <xsl:with-param name="pSales" select="/*/*"/>
   <xsl:with-param name="pPriceName" select="$pPriceName"/>
   <xsl:with-param name="pQuantityName"
        select="$pQuantityName"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="totalSales">
  <xsl:param name="pAccum" select="0"/>
  <xsl:param name="pSales"/>
  <xsl:param name="pPriceName"/>
  <xsl:param name="pQuantityName"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vthisSale" select="$pSales[1]"/>

  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="not($vthisSale)">
    <xsl:value-of select="$pAccum"/>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:call-template name="totalSales">
     <xsl:with-param name="pAccum" select=
     "$pAccum
     +
       $vthisSale/*[name()=$pPriceName]
      *
       $vthisSale/*[name()=$pQuantityName]
      "/>
      <xsl:with-param name="pSales" select=
       "$pSales[position() >1]"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="pPriceName"
           select="$pPriceName"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="pQuantityName"
           select="$pQuantityName"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (you could at least provide this!):

```
<orders>
 <order>
  <price1>10</price1>
  <quantity1>3</quantity1>
  <price2>15</price2>
  <quantity2>1</quantity2>
 </order>
 <order>
  <price1>11</price1>
  <quantity1>2</quantity1>
  <price2>9</price2>
  <quantity2>3</quantity2>
 </order>
</orders>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
63
```

**Do note**: The values of the names of the child elements to serve as price and quantity are provided as external parameters to the transformation and can be known only at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot.
All I need is the '`Price`' and `$vthisSale/*[name()=$pPriceName]`

It really help!! I have been stuck for ages because of the magic ' '

Comment: @Franky: please for this time and next, think of getting better involved on how SO works. Make sure to read about how to [accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and [upvote responsibly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59828/how-to-upvote-responsibly).