# xsl recursive nested calls sums of multiplications

Tags: xslt, recursion, report, reporting

I have a similar problem to that solved in this link
[XSL - sum multiplication of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551324/xsl-sum-multiplication-of-elements)

my problem is, I have orders instead of just items, and each order can have one or more items.

at the end I need is the cost of all orders, (besides have to multiply each cost by the quantity)
I had resolved with xsl 2, but reports only supports 1.0

```
<root>
    <order>
      <item type="goods">
        <quantity unit="pcs">1</quantity>
        <cost>2.89</cost>
      </item>
      <item type="goods">
        <quantity unit="pcs">10</quantity>
        <cost>210.25</cost>
      </item>
    </order>
    <order>
      <item type="goods">
        <quantity unit="pcs">1</quantity>
        <cost>4.15</cost>
      </item>
    </order>
    <order>
      <item type="goods">
        <quantity unit="pcs">5</quantity>
        <cost>1.25</cost>
      </item>
      <item type="goods">
        <quantity unit="pcs">20</quantity>
        <cost>189.63</cost>
      </item>     
      <item type="goods">
        <quantity unit="pcs">3</quantity>
        <cost>1</cost>
      </item>     
      <item type="goods">
        <quantity unit="pcs">9</quantity>
        <cost>6</cost>
      </item>     
    </order>    
</root>
```

Comment: What should the output look like? Just a single number with the grand total of all orders? What XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: in fact a couple of thing more, but in this case yes, just the grand total.
<pre><code><xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:sw="http://www.interapptive.com/shipworks" extension-element-prefixes="sw"></code></pre>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the grand total, then this should do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="GetGrandTotal">
      <xsl:with-param name="items" select="//item" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="GetGrandTotal">
    <xsl:param name="items" />
    <xsl:param name="total" select="0" />

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not($items)">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number($total, '0.00')"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:call-template name="GetGrandTotal">
          <xsl:with-param name="items" select="$items[position() > 1]" />
          <xsl:with-param name="total"
                          select="$total + ($items[1]/quantity * $items[1]/cost)" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, the result is:

```
5965.39
```